# Is the statement of the theorem correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I have been asked to prove this::

> $f,g$ are polynomials over a field $F$ .Prove that if $f,g$ are relatively prime then $f,g$ have no common roots in any extension of $F$.

But I wonder why is this true if I consider

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=(x+i)(x-i)(x+2i)(x-2i)\\
g(x)&=(x+i)(x-i)(x+3)(x-3)
\end{align*}$$

then they are relatively prime in $\mathbb{R}$  but have roots in common in $\mathbb{C}$.

Is the statement wrong, or there is some fault in my argument? Please help.

Comment: To follow up Zed's statement: it is true that $f$ and $g$ have no common *linear* factors over $\Bbb R$ but those are not the only primes in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Answer (score 3):

They are not relatively prime in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ since they have a common factor of $x^2+1$:

$$\begin{align*}
f&=(x^2+1)(x^2+4)\\
g&=(x^2+1)(x-3)(x+3)
\end{align*}$$